# Open files (or apps) and position them on appropriate screen respectively

Tags: python

Open files(or apps) and position them on appropriate screen respectively.

I have files and apps which are required to open daily.

```
cmds = [
'open task_record.md',
'open diary.md',
'open terminal',
'open chrome'
]

for i in cmds:
    os.popen('{}'.format(i))
```

After they are opened, I draw them to appropriate screen one by one.

I decide to solve the problem and read over the standard lib with no hints provided.

How to posit each on appropriate screen?
(Mac OS)

Comment: This has nothing to do with Python, the 'open' command is native from OS X, open a terminal and type 'open' since it needs more arguments it will show its help text.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/open.1.html

Comment: Why are you using `popen()`? Are you trying to interact with the applications?